# Can I access public:// from inside a module?

Tags: 7, uri

I need to load an image that's uploaded to the public folder from within a module

In the module itself:

```
function mymodule_dashboard() {
   GLOBAL $user;
   $profile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid, 'personal_information');
   $data['avatar'] = $profile->field_picture['und'][0]['uri'];
```

In my dashboard.tpl.php:

```
<img src="<?php echo $data['avatar']; ?>" />
```

The rendered content:

```
<img src="public://image.jpg">
```

I can pull the image name and build the path myself, but I'm looking for a way to actually take advantage of this public folder business

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the [`file_create_url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) function:

> Creates a web-accessible URL for a stream to an external or local file.

e.g.

```
$data['avatar'] = file_create_url($profile->field_picture['und'][0]['uri']);
```

Comment: aha! so THAT's how that's supposed to work.. :p perfect.